# Добавляет пустые строки в бд

Tags: php

Хочу добавить в бд запись пишу в адресную строку http://project-546564.codeanyapp.com/news/add?name=Koly?age=27 и он не добавляет запись, а выдает ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error! Warning! Achtung! Danger! in ....php:35 Stack trace: #0 ....php(32): core\FactoryRouting::getController('/news/add?name=...') #1 {main} thrown in ...php on line 35 но когда я пишу просто http://project-546564.codeanyapp.com/news/add он добавляет пустую строчку в бд.

```
public function add(){ 
  $params = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);  
  $params = $params[1];   
  parse_str($params, $arr);
  $mysqli = new \mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "quest");    
  $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO users SET name = '{$arr["name"]}', age = '{$arr["age"]}';");
}
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: очевидно в первом случае у тебя не справляется маршрутизатор (FactoryRouting::getController), который возможно криво написан, во втором т.к. нет данных - то он тебе и заносит пустоту

Comment: А как определить почему не справляется маршрутизатор?

Comment: Надо смотреть внутрь него и смотреть чего там написано. Включить отладчик и посмотреть как происходит запрос и разбор строк... судя по тексту ошибки - это какой-то самопал

Comment: А почему в GET два (?)  /add?name=Koly?age=27  вместо второго должен быть &

Comment: @ВладимирМикитюк кстати скорее всего в этом и проблема)

Comment: Не удивлюсь, если 35 строчка это `parse_str($params, $arr);` и ругается на `$arr`, которой в функции просто неоткуда взяться

Answer (score 0):

там ещё непонятно INSERT +  SET + кавычки(") + (;)  как то не по феншую
я бы сделал так:

```
$mysqli -> query( "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES( '$arr[name]', '$arr[age]')" );
```